# What is the Ruby/Rails equivalent of Python's urllib.quote_plus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, urlencode

Basically url escapes a string except uses '+' instead of '%20' for spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CGI::escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/CGI.src/M000532.html) does just that:

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'cgi'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> CGI::escape("foo and/or bar")
=> "foo+and%2For+bar"
```

Comment: BTW, CGI::escape does not allow specifying a set of characters that are NOT to be escaped, like urllib.quote_plus does:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html